# Renaming factor levels using a subset of the factor self in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a sample factor:

```
x <- factor(c("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "alpha", "beta"))

# Output
> x
[1] alpha beta  gamma alpha beta 
Levels: alpha beta gamma
```

The factor levels can be renamed in several ways (described [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Renaming_levels_of_a_factor/) in the Cookbook for R). The `revalue()` function of the  `plyr` library is an option:

```
library(plyr)
revalue(x, c("beta" = "two", "gamma"="three"))

# Output   
> revalue(x, c("beta" = "two", "gamma"="three"))
[1] alpha two   three alpha two  
Levels: alpha two three
```

**Problem**

I would like to use the `revalue()` function inside a function, so I thought it would be possible to use subsetting of the factor in the `revalue()` function:

```
revalue(x, c(x[2] = "two", x[3]="three"))
```

This produces the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "revalue(x, c(paste(x[2]) ="
```

Next, I tried the `paste()` function:

```
revalue(x, c(paste(x[2]) = "two", x[3]="three"))
```

Sadly, with the same error.

**Question**

What is happening here? Since `paste(x[2])` equals `"beta"`, I thought it should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
plyr::revalue(x, setNames(c("two", "three"), x[2:3]))
#[1] alpha two   three alpha two  
#Levels: alpha two three
```

Note that

```
setNames
function (object = nm, nm) 
{
    names(object) <- nm
    object
}
```

---

Or another option is `fct_recode`

```
library(forcats)
fct_recode(x, two = as.character(x[2]), three = as.character(x[3]))
#[1] alpha two   three alpha two  
 #Levels: alpha two three
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! However, I do not understand the note on the function? Is there something to look out for?

Comment: @user213544  It is just a note to show that `setNames` does the `names(y) <-` internally

Answer (score 0):

`c()` doesn't like it for some reason. Can always assign names after e.g.

```
y <- c("two", "three")
names(y) <- x[2:3]
revalue(x, y)
```